# What is the Java library to popup an AzureAD browser for user login user then and output a token?

Tags: java, azure-active-directory, adal, mps

I am developing a solution that needs an token to request a rest API. I want in the beginning of my code to popup a window to user and receive an answer with a token.

I am developing an intention at JetBrains MPS that demands permission from the user to do so. I read this on GitHub:  https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-java/

The problem is that I need to input the  username and password as a string, not through a Azure site.

I wish my code could look like this

```
azureADHelper foo = new azureADHelper()
string userType = "admin"
string companyWebName = "https://stackoverflow.com/"
foo.askUserIdentity(userType, companyWebName)
if (foo.permission == true){
    string token = foo.getToken()
}
```

Comment: The Java library for Azure AD auth is adal4j. You can refer to https://github.com/azure-samples/active-directory-java-webapp-openidconnect

Answer (score 0):

Azure Active Directory provides several libraries for different platform. For java "**ADAL4J**" library is used.

I hope the below code screenshot will help to address your issue:

[image]

You can check the below sample to configure azure ad in java.

https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-java-webapp-openidconnect